# UDP WSARecvMsg return WSAEWOULDBLOCK but Wireshark catch packets

Tags: sockets, wireshark

I have a problem while reading data from UDP socket (port 7078). I've called WSARecvMsg function and received WSAEWOULDBLOCK error. But, Wireshark catch incoming UDP packet on port 7078! Please help me!

This is my code for creating and binding socket

```
static ortp_socket_t create_and_bind(const char *addr, int *port, int *sock_family, bool_t reuse_addr){
    int err;
    int optval = 1;
    ortp_socket_t sock=-1;
    char num[8];
    struct addrinfo hints, *res0, *res;

    if (*port==-1) *port=0;
    if (*port==0) reuse_addr=FALSE;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    snprintf(num, sizeof(num), "%d",*port);
    err = getaddrinfo(addr,num, &hints, &res0);
    if (err!=0) {
        ortp_warning ("Error in getaddrinfo on (addr=%s port=%i): %s", addr, *port, gai_strerror(err));
        return -1;
    }

    for (res = res0; res; res = res->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, 0);
        if (sock==-1)
            continue;

        if (reuse_addr){
            err = setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                    (SOCKET_OPTION_VALUE)&optval, sizeof (optval));
            if (err < 0)
            {
                ortp_warning ("Fail to set rtp address reusable: %s.", getSocketError());
            }
        }
        err = 0;
        switch (res->ai_family) {
            default:
            case AF_INET:
                break;
            case AF_INET6:
                break;
        }
        if (err < 0) {
            ortp_warning("Fail to set recv TTL/HL socket option: %s.", getSocketError());
        }

        *sock_family=res->ai_family;
        err = bind (sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
        if (err != 0){
            ortp_debug ("Fail to bind rtp socket to (addr=%s port=%i) : %s.", addr, *port, getSocketError());
            close_socket (sock);
            sock=-1;
            continue;
        }
        switch (res->ai_family)
          {
            case AF_INET:
              if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr)))
            {
                  struct ip_mreq mreq;
              mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
              mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
              err = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (SOCKET_OPTION_VALUE) &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
              if (err < 0){
                ortp_warning ("Fail to join address group: %s.", getSocketError());
                close_socket (sock);
                sock=-1;
                continue;
                }
            }
              break;
            case AF_INET6:
              if (IN6_IS_ADDR_MULTICAST(&(((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr)))
            {
              struct ipv6_mreq mreq;
              mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr = ((struct sockaddr_in6 *) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
              mreq.ipv6mr_interface = 0;
              err = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, (SOCKET_OPTION_VALUE)&mreq, sizeof(mreq));
              if (err < 0)
                {
                  ortp_warning ("Fail to join address group: %s.", getSocketError());
                  close_socket (sock);
                  sock=-1;
                  continue;
                }
            }
              break;
          }
        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res0);

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)
    if (ortp_WSARecvMsg == NULL) {
        GUID guid = WSAID_WSARECVMSG;
        DWORD bytes_returned;
        if (WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &guid, sizeof(guid),
            &ortp_WSARecvMsg, sizeof(ortp_WSARecvMsg), &bytes_returned, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            ortp_warning("WSARecvMsg function not found.");
        }
    }
#endif
    if (sock!=-1){
        set_non_blocking_socket (sock);
        if (*port==0){
            struct sockaddr_storage saddr;
            socklen_t slen=sizeof(saddr);
            err=getsockname(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&saddr,&slen);
            if (err==-1){
                ortp_error("getsockname(): %s",getSocketError());
                close(sock);
                return (ortp_socket_t)-1;
            }
            err=getnameinfo((struct sockaddr*)&saddr, slen, NULL, 0, num, sizeof(num), NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
            if (err!=0){
                ortp_error("getnameinfo(): %s",gai_strerror(err));
                close(sock);
                return (ortp_socket_t)-1;
            }
            *port=atoi(num);
        }

    }
    return sock;
```

}

And I use WSAIoctl to get WSARECVMSG function pointer

```
typedef INT  (WINAPI * LPFN_WSARECVMSG)(SOCKET, LPWSAMSG, LPDWORD, LPWSAOVERLAPPED, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE);
static LPFN_WSARECVMSG ortp_WSARecvMsg = NULL;
if (ortp_WSARecvMsg == NULL) {
        GUID guid = WSAID_WSARECVMSG;
        DWORD bytes_returned;
        if (WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER, &guid, sizeof(guid),
            &ortp_WSARecvMsg, sizeof(ortp_WSARecvMsg), &bytes_returned, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            ortp_warning("WSARecvMsg function not found.");
        }
}
```

My code for receiving data

```
int rtp_session_rtp_recv_abstract(ortp_socket_t socket, mblk_t *msg, int flags, struct sockaddr *from, socklen_t *fromlen) {
    int ret;
    int bufsz = (int) (msg->b_datap->db_lim - msg->b_datap->db_base);
    char control[512];
    WSAMSG msghdr;
    WSACMSGHDR *cmsghdr;
    WSABUF data_buf;
    DWORD bytes_received;
    if (ortp_WSARecvMsg == NULL) {
        return recvfrom(socket, (char *)msg->b_wptr, bufsz, flags, from, fromlen);
    }

    memset(&msghdr, 0, sizeof(msghdr));
    memset(control, 0, sizeof(control));
    if(from != NULL && fromlen != NULL) {
        msghdr.name = from;
        msghdr.namelen = *fromlen;
    }
    data_buf.buf = (char *)msg->b_wptr;
    data_buf.len = bufsz;
    msghdr.lpBuffers = &data_buf;
    msghdr.dwBufferCount = 1;
    msghdr.Control.buf = control;
    msghdr.Control.len = sizeof(control);
    msghdr.dwFlags = flags;
    ret = ortp_WSARecvMsg(socket, &msghdr, &bytes_received, NULL, NULL);
    if(fromlen != NULL)
        *fromlen = msghdr.namelen;
    if(ret >= 0) {
        ret = bytes_received;
    }
    else 
    {
        int i;
        long m_ErrorCode = WSAGetLastError();
        i = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Perhaps the incoming packets are being blocked by Windows Firewall (or similar)?